# Read/Write data in Excel (XLSB) in java

Tags: java, excel, xlsb

Are there any libraries available for writing large amounts of data in Excel (XLSB) in java?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to [smartxls](http://www.smartxls.com/java/workbook.htm#vworkbook-rw-xlsb)

Comment: See also [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com)